# CHROME AUTOMATICALLY OPENS WINDOWS ON PRESSING SPACEBAR OR ARROW KEYS

Tags: google-chrome

In windows 8.1 pc, chrome automatically opens multiple windows on pressing space bar or arrow keys in any app's (including chrome) session/window. This happens in all the user accounts in the pc. What would be the reason and solution..help pls

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have some malware. Try scanning your computer using the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) and the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). If that doesn't work, follow [this guide](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/malware-removal-guide-for-windows/).